# How can I construct the URL of images stored on a private server?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, vpn, nsurl

For some context, I am writing an iPhone app that must fetch a large (~500 MB) batch of PNG images on first launch.  During my research, I came across AFNetworking and NSURLSession as possible means of getting an image, but both of these APIs require a URL using, for example,

```
NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/images/imageName.png"];
```

My question is, if the images or image data I'm trying to retrieve are not in some public domain like http://www.google.com, but rather some private server at a known IP address such as my DigitalOcean droplet, how do I retrieve or construct its URL?

I do know the exact path to the image on the server, just not how to get to the server from iOS, as all the examples I found on stackoverflow assume I am using a standard `http://` web address.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this article on how to assign/get the public IP address from your DigitalOcean droplet. `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-floating-ips-on-digitalocean`

It's quite long as it is vendor specific. However, using the public ip address on AFNetworking should work.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful link.  It is very insightful.  Interesting how it is vendor-specific.. so the app/API is at the mercy of the server provider, then?  Other apps/companies follow their own protocol for addressing their private servers (for example, they buy/build their own server machines, and have to address them themselves)?  To stay on-topic: once I get that floating public ip address, how do I turn that into NSURL or its AFNetworking wrapper?

Comment: Well the vendor specific part is how to apply a static ip address or a domain name to your server. Once you have an ip address or domain name associated to your server just construct the NSURL like so: http://<the ip address or domain>:<port>/path/to/your/api. The ip address is like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and the port is usually 80 or 443.

Comment: Is there any way to check this (as a sanity test) through the browser or some other means?  I tried http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:80/root/topFolder/imageName.png and get a "Problem loading page" error.  Firefox cannot seem to connect to the server, as if the webpage does not exist.

Comment: The browser should be able to load it. Either the path is wrong or the droplet is not properly configured for that ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
http://www.google.com
```

with your IP address

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:<port>
```

And even

```
http://localhost:8080
```

works if you're testing locally.

---

Note that domain is just a human readable name to help people remember & type easily, it'll return server's IP finally at behind.

Btw, I suggest you use domain w/ CNAME record to refer to your server, in case your server is down or you want to change a server in the future, so you just need to change domain's CNAME record w/o bothering to deploy a new App version that only for changing the url.

Comment: Thanks! Where would I know my <port> value?  When you say CNAME record, is that something that would come with registering/purchasing a domain?  Because I do have one for my homepage, but never thought of using the domain (and haven't heard of CNAME) as an interface for the app to pull images..

Comment: @Cindeselia _"Where would I know my <port> value"_: need to check your server, in ur case, check digitalOcean's. u can try w/o it first. And for CNAME record, it's generally for subdomain, like <sub_domain>.<ur_domain>.com, ur home page might use A record, for more detail, u can search for it to get a better understanding, or just ask for a customer service of ur domain registrars (like godaddy.com, etc) ;)

Comment: Is there a way to test this from the browser?  I tried subbing in my IP and cannot seem to load the image.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Cindeselia 1. make sure ur server's related port (e.g. 8080) is open; 2. make sure the url is correct.  Try to open it in ur browser, c whether it's accessable.

Comment: Regarding 1., how do I open a port?  I googled this and found a bunch of different forums, some using iptables, myfirewall, ..., and even one with nodejs. Sorry to sound like a n00b, but why aren't traditional ports or one port open by default?  If I open a port, does it stay open forever?  Never realized that accessing a server for images was so complicated...

Comment: @Cindeselia some suppliers have their console panel to handle several settings, including ports, like AWS. Generally, i use iptables, if u use Ubuntu as the system for ur DO server, u can take a look at this tutorial offered by DO: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04. And yes, once the port is open, it'll stay open untill u close it. Open port or not depends on ur server's usage, like ur case, u'd better to open 80 to allow HTTP access. u can get a port list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: @Cindeselia _"but why aren't traditional ports or one port open by default"_ for security reason, like DDOS attack. But indeed there're some ports open by default, like 22, for SSH remote login to server. for 80, some open it by default, some not. Cause not every server will be used as web server.